# Persistent data on external HDD

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, external-hdd, persistence

my dad's HDD has died in his laptop but he does not want me to open it up. It has been running Lubuntu for over a year but refuses to run Windows, but it is really ugly and hard for him to use. I plan to install Ubuntu 14 on an old HDD from my laptop with the SATA to USB caddy I just bought, and have at least 20gb of free space for him to use. Seeing as FAT32 has it's limitations would it be best to partition the drive before installing Ubuntu to the HDD and having the secondary partition for data and primary for the Live CD? Would this work or would Ubuntu not mount the partition at boot and allow programs to be installed to it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  Why don't you just install ubuntu to the drive normally ( which would format it for ext4 ).  Also explain to your dad that swapping the hard disk is about impossible to mess up; all it takes is the ability to use a screwdriver.

Comment: I'm an old fart too: just put the external drive in the caddy, hook it up to his machine, install Ubuntu on the external drive (reformatting it completely) and have the BIOS boot from the external drive.  The day he forgets the external drive or gets fed up with pressing the [F12] key (be sure not to change the BIOS), tell him you wanted to do it on the internal drive all along and shouldn't you just move it into his computer right now?  >:)